# How can I increase the overall height of my slider using CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, height

See link: [bit.ly/Mh9PGJ](http://bit.ly/Mh9PGJ)

When I make my browser window smaller, eventually 'Commercial Management' is too big for its slider box and gets shifted about. The best solution I believe is to simply increase the overall height of the entire entity (including every slider) so that the text has more space. But for this to work I'm guessing you would need some kind of min-height property there.

My problem is that I've tried min-height on practically everything there and I end up with odd-looking results, like the content expands but the green sliders do not, etc.

Any solution at all to this problem would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: posting to a site doesn't help future users. Please post pertinent code and **show us** what you have tried. Set up a Fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 0):

possible solution can be
adding your h2 class to those attributes

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

it is not the correct way but at least if you dont have enough space, you can simple finish the word with ...[3 Dots]